# Is there a reason my CTE with a basic subquery in the second stage of the CTE is failing?

Tags: sql-server, cte

Ok... anyone aid with this sorry...i've been playing with some of my works reports and i thought id found a way to mix two results into one when i came across a small issue...

if i run my CTE code below without the lower subquery it runs straight away...

```
WITH CTE_RealAudit (UserName,WorkstationName,LoginDate,LoginTime,"Days","Hours","Minutes","Seconds")
AS
(
SELECT UserName AS 'User',WorkstationName AS 'Workstation',
RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(ss, StartTime + DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),'19700101'))),2)+'/'+RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(m,dateadd(ss, StartTime + DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),'19700101'))),2)+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(4),DATEPART(yy,dateadd(ss, StartTime + DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),'19700101'))) AS 'Login Date',
RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(hh,DATEADD(ss, StartTime + DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),'19700101'))),2)+':'+RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(mi,dateadd(ss, StartTime + DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),'19700101'))),2)+':'+RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(ss,dateadd(ss, StartTime + DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),'19700101'))),2) AS "Login Time",
CONVERT(varchar(2), SUM(EndTime-StartTime)/(3600*24)) AS 'Days',
CONVERT(varchar(2), SUM(EndTime-StartTime)/3600) AS 'Hours',
CONVERT(varchar(2), (SUM(EndTime-StartTime) % 3600) / 60) AS 'Minutes',
CONVERT(varchar(2), (SUM(EndTime-StartTime) % 60 )) AS 'Seconds'
    FROM IMuse.vAuditUsageAndNames
        WHERE StartTime BETWEEN DATEDIFF(ss,'19700101',DATEADD(dd,-3000,CONVERT(date,SYSDATETIME()))) 
        AND DATEDIFF(ss,'19700101',CONVERT(date,SYSDATETIME())) 
        AND LEFT(UserName,2) <> N'P-'
        AND LEFT(UserName,3) <> N'EP-'
        AND EndTime <> StartTime
    GROUP BY UserName,WorkstationName,StartTime
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_RealAudit
    WHERE "Hours" <> N'0' 
    AND "Minutes" <> N'0
```

but if i add a subquery to the last select such as

```
SELECT * FROM CTE_RealAudit
    WHERE "Hours" <> N'0' 
    AND "Minutes" IN    
    (select Minutes from cte_realaudit)
```

or my goal

```
SELECT * FROM CTE_RealAudit
    WHERE "Hours" <> N'0' 
    AND "Minutes" IN    
    (SELECT "Minutes" from CTE_RealAudit
        where "Hours" >= N'0'
        and "Minutes" >= N'0')
```

it completely freaks out and takes 20+ minutes? anyone aid in why this is occurring?

newbie here so sorry if im doing something totally stupid.

thanks

Comment: `Hours` and `Minutes` are sums. Why are you converting them to strings (and then compare them to `'0'`)? What if you first compare them and then convert them to string (which I guess is only for display)

Comment: Another wonder is can these sums ever be negative?

Comment: they can never be negative but can be 0 and for some reason occasionally days show as * ... that part isnt my code but you are correct i can remove the convert part of those lines, but that still doesnt aid, the full query itself is fine up until i try to add the subquery to the last select in the CTE

Comment: post the query plan, please

Comment: im still waiting for it to complete... i will post ASAP, has anyone ever done the subquery within the select part of a CTE before?

Comment: The whole subquery condition seems fishy: `"Minutes" IN (select Minutes ...)` What exactly is this part trying to do?

Comment: well if i ever get a situation where hours = 1 and minutes = 0 i want to keep that data, and for some reason if i do a normal WHERE minutes <>0 AND hours <>0 it doesnt do as id expect...
how do i add an attachment to add the query plan? its finished at 29 minutes, where as if i create a temp table, do a select into, and drop my non required data it takes a second....

Comment: Perhaps you want `WHERE (minutes > 0 OR hours > 0)`? If this is the condition you want, you'd probably better using: `SUM(EndTime-StartTime) > 0` and no subquery at all.

Comment: but wont that not show me the 0s? i.e. will i still lose the ones where its 1 hour 0 minutes 30 seconds? because the or hits?

Comment: maybe it help if i explained my intended result set
my query pulls in data from the DB and converts it to date in a break down of days, hours, minutes and seconds, what i want out of this query is to view all data except where the hours are 0 and the minutes are 0, but i do want to continue seeing 0 minutes if the hours are above 0, i successfully did this by forcing the creation of a table and deleting all of the non-required data with a delete where hours = 0 and minutes = 0 but i was hoping to change it into a CTE and a select, but the only way i think i can do that is with the subquery

Comment: Judging by the object name, I assume the CTE is selecting from a view? Is this a complicated view?

Comment: its using a common table expression - a virtual table that only exists during the operation of the with command

Comment: A CTE isn't a virtual table like a temporary is - it's a subquery that you can reference multiple times. If you refer to it twice, like you are, it'll run the whole subquery twice (kinda).

Answer (score 3):

Let's pretend for a moment that `CTE_RealAudit` is a normal table...

You're querying it twice! Once to get the list of `Minutes` values, and to get all the other fields for those rows that have a `Minutes` value (oh, and surely it always will have, unless you have NULLs) in the list. So yes, that's going to take a lot longer than querying it once.

So that's why it's taking much longer. But I don't think you need to query it twice at all - have a good think about the logic you actually want, especially as it's not a normal table, but rather a complex subquery over a view.

Comment: ok i guess that makes sense... but if i did all of this manually and put it into a real table it runs instantly still, it only has issues when running in a CTE? is that normal?

so if i do a select into instead of a with, and then use the lower query on that table it runs instantly... but running it through a CTE takes 30 mins?

Comment: No, it's about the complexity of the CTE and the view that's referenced.